# How can I show days by group like Whatsapp chat screen?

Tags: react-native, chat, whatsapp

How can I excatly do a similar Date system like the one in the Whatsapp chat screen?

As you can see the messages are in a group by date, I mean they are separated by date.

Here is a ScreenShot that i found for better explanation:

[image: Example]

I do this in a FlatList, while rendering the messages one by one.

Here is what i did

```
        let previousDate = "";
    if (index > 0) {
        previousDate = moment(this.state.messages[index - 1].created_at).format(
            "L"
        );
    } else {
        previousDate = moment(this.state.messages.created_at).format("L");
    }

    let currentDate = moment(item.created_at).format("L");
```

So, i created a functional component for `renderItem` prop of the FlatList, so `item` and `index` comes from the actual data from the FlatList.

What i'm trying to do here is, basically grabbing the current rendering item's `created_at` and compare it with the previous item's `created_at`, and to do that, i'm using the original data which is stored in the state. But unfortunately when the FlatList rendering the very first item which has index number `0` there is no previous element to compare in the original data in state, that's why i checking if is greater than 0 go and grab date from previous indexed item. And in the Else case, which means when rendering the first item,  do not look for previous item and just get the `created_at`.

And below i check if the `currentDate` and `previousDate`s are NOT the same, render a custom component else do not render anything.

```
    {previousDate && !moment(currentDate).isSame(previousDate, "day") ? ( // custom component) : null}
```

It's should work like that, but the major problem is, i used `inverted` FlatList for to able to messages go from bottom of the screen to the top. But now, becouse of it's a inverted flatlist the items being rendering from bottom to the top and it gives me result like this:

[image]

NOTE: At the beginning the messages were coming also reversed but i fixed this with sending them also reversed from the DB.

So, i don't know how do i able to achieve my goal, and do it like on the first picture.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you fix this ?... Trying the same but on react

Comment: not yet, its still on my TODO list

Comment: @Ozzie did you manage to implement this? if you did, can you please post your answer here, I'm struggling to get this working...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use a helper function (`generateItems`) to address the problem that you are describing. Here is the code that I use to group my messages by day and then render either a `<Message />` or a `<Day />` in the `renderItem` prop. This is using an `inverted` `FlatList` as you described.

```js
import moment from 'moment';

function groupedDays(messages) {
  return messages.reduce((acc, el, i) => {
    const messageDay = moment(el.created_at).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    if (acc[messageDay]) {
      return { ...acc, [messageDay]: acc[messageDay].concat([el]) };
    }
    return { ...acc, [messageDay]: [el] };
  }, {});
}

function generateItems(messages) {
  const days = groupedDays(messages);
  const sortedDays = Object.keys(days).sort(
    (x, y) => moment(y, 'YYYY-MM-DD').unix() - moment(x, 'YYYY-MM-DD').unix()
  );
  const items = sortedDays.reduce((acc, date) => {
    const sortedMessages = days[date].sort(
      (x, y) => new Date(y.created_at) - new Date(x.created_at)
    );
    return acc.concat([...sortedMessages, { type: 'day', date, id: date }]);
  }, []);
  return items;
}

export default generateItems;
```

For reference here is my list as well as the `renderItem` function:

```js
<MessageList
  data={generatedItems}
  extraData={generatedItems}
  inverted
  keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
  renderItem={renderItem}
/>

function renderItem({ item }) {
  if (item.type && item.type === 'day') {
    return <Day {...item} />;
  }
  return <Message {...item} />;
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you 4 your response. Very interesting example im gonna try it out...I hope you understood my problem while writing this. becouse for me,  separating the renderItwem element is it day or message, i do the similar thing inside of the item, as a title, but becouse of flatlist is inverted i was pputting the date at the end of the component instead of header. i hope your example will help me out... thank you

Comment: <<return messages.reduce((acc, el, i)>>, in here what are the acc, el and i.

Comment: @SulakshithaRathnayake These are the standard variables for the `reduce` method: accumulator, element, and index. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Ok. got it. Thank you Matt.

Comment: data and extraData are same function, generatedItems?

Answer (score 1):

This is how i did it in react,

1. Create a `new Set()` to store dates uniquely

```c
const dates = new Set();
```

2. When looping through chats array, check if date already exists in unique `Set` before rendering date

```c
chats.map((chat) => {
  
  // For easier uniqueness check,
  // Formated date string example '16082021'
  const dateNum = format(chat.timestamp, 'ddMMyyyy');

  return (
    <React.Fragment key={chat.chat_key}>

      // Do not render date if it already exists in set
      {dates.has(dateNum) ? null : renderDate(chat, dateNum)}

      <ChatroomChatBubble chat={chat} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
});
```

3. Finally, when date has been rendered, add date num into array so it doesn't render again

```c
const renderDate = (chat, dateNum) => {
  const timestampDate = format(chat.timestamp, 'EEEE, dd/MM/yyyy');

  // Add to Set so it does not render again
  dates.add(dateNum);

  return <Text>{timestampDate}</Text>;
};
```

Comment: Is this approach is using `FlatList`? or just `.map()`? If not using `FlatList` in RN I think is not good for the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete solution in react. Just copy it and change the array according to your requirments and it will work. For styling i am using tailwindCss. You can replace styling with your requirements.

Component MessageList

```js
import moment from 'moment';
import React from 'react';
import Message from './message';

const MessageList = React.memo(({ messages }) => {

    const msgDates = new Set();

    const formatMsgDate = (created_date) => {

        const today = moment().startOf('day');
        const msgDate = moment(created_date);
        let dateDay = '';

        if(msgDate.isSame(today, 'day')){
            dateDay = 'Today';
        }
        else if (msgDate.isSame(today.clone().subtract(1, 'days'), 'day')){
            dateDay = 'Yesterday';
        }
        else{
            dateDay = msgDate.format('MMMM D, YYYY');
        }

        return dateDay
    }

    const renderMsgDate = (message, nextMessage) => {
        const dateTimeStamp = moment(message.created, 'YYYY-MM-DD').valueOf();
        let nextMsgdateTimeStamp = '';
        if(nextMessage){
            nextMsgdateTimeStamp = moment(nextMessage.created, 'YYYY-MM-DD').valueOf();
        }

        if(msgDates.has(dateTimeStamp) || (nextMsgdateTimeStamp && nextMsgdateTimeStamp == dateTimeStamp)){
            return null
        }
        else{
            
            msgDates.add(dateTimeStamp);

            return (
                <div className='py-2 flex justify-center items-center'>
                    <span id="msg_day" className='px-2 py-1 shadow font-medium rounded-lg text-gray-400 bg-white border-gray-300'>
                        {formatMsgDate(message.created)}
                    </span>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            {messages?.map((message, index) => (
                <>
                    <Message key={index} msg={message} />
                    {renderMsgDate(message, messages[index+1])}
                </>
            ))}
        </>
    );
});

export default MessageList;
```

Message Component

```js
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import ReactTimeAgo from 'react-time-ago'
import { useGroupChatContext } from '../../context/groupchatContext';

const Message = React.memo(({ msg }) => {

  const groupChatContext = useGroupChatContext();

  const {authData} = useMemo(() => ({
    authData: groupChatContext.authData,
  }));


  return (
    <div className={`flex gap-3 pb-4 ${msg.nurse_id == authData?.id ? 'flex-row-reverse text-start' : 'w-full'}`}>


        <div className={`${msg.nurse_id == authData.id ? 'text-right' : 'text-left'}`}>
          <h2 className=" text-sm font-semibold ml-2"> {msg.nurse_id == authData.id ? null : msg.sender} <span className="text-xs text-gray-500 ml-2">{msg.status == 'sending' ? 'Sending...' : <ReactTimeAgo timeStyle="twitter-first-minute" date={new Date(msg.created)} />}</span></h2>
          <div className="mt-1 flex flex-col gap-2">
            <div className={`rounded-md ${msg.nurse_id == authData.id ? 'bg-bg-primary': 'bg-white' }  p-2 shadow`}>
              <p className={`${msg.nurse_id == authData.id ? 'text-white': 'text-gray-800' } text-start`} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: msg.message?.text }}></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
});

export default Message;
```

The final Result

[image: screenshot]